# elastic search query for aggregating on sub-fields of array

Tags: elasticsearch

My elastic search index contain data in such format, the data is an array of object which contain date , order, visit for that date on that term :-

```
  {
"term": "ふるさと納税",    
  "data": [

        {
          "date": "2018-01-25",
          "visits": 17670,
          "ranking": 1,
          "orders": 154
        },
        {
          "date": "2018-02-14",
          "visits": 13758,
          "ranking": 1,
          "orders": 116
        },
        {
          "date": "2017-12-24",
          "visits": 142578,
          "ranking": 1,
          "orders": 2565
        },
        {
          "date": "2018-03-08",
          "visits": 21799,
          "ranking": 1,
          "orders": 312
        }
    ]
 },{
      "term": "帯　中古　振袖",
      "data": [
        {
          "date": "2018-01-30",
          "ranking": 2966,
          "orders": 0,
          "visits": 345
        }
      ]
    }
```

i would like to sum all the visits and orders for the term within a defined date range

I have created this query :-

```
{
 "_source": [],
  "query": {
"bool": {
  "filter": [
    {"range": {"data.date": {"gte" : "2018-03-21"}}},
    {"range": {"data.date": {"lte" : "2018-03-21"}}}
  ]
}
   },
   "aggs" : {
"by_term": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "term",
    "order":{"sum_ranking":"desc"},
    "size":100
     },"aggs": {
      "sum_ranking":  {
        "sum": {
          "field" : "data.visits"
       }
    }
  }
}
  },
"from" : 0, 
"size" : 0
 }
```

it seems the filter is not working .
can any one help.

The mapping is  :-

```
{

"settings" : {

    "number_of_shards" : 1

},

"mappings" : {

    "keyword" : {

        "properties" : {

            "term" : { "type" : "keyword" }

        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Can you show your mapping? Is the `data` field `nested`? Do you have other fields than `data` and `ふるさと納税` in your document?

Comment: no the data field is not nested

Comment: So you have two options: either you make the `data` field nested in your mapping or you create one document per data element and insert the term inside that document.